# Binning a series returns a seemingly unrelated TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to slice a dataframe I created into bins:

[picture of dataframe in case it's relevant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4bAn.jpg)

```
# create bins and labels
bins = [575, 600, 625, 650]
labels = [
    "$575-$599",
    "$600-$624",
    "$625-$649",
    "$650-$675"
]

schoolSummary["Spending Range"] = pd.cut(schoolSummary["Per Student Budget"], bins, labels = labels)
```

For some reason, I receive this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-b938397739fa> in <module>()
      9 
     10 #schoolSummary["Spending Range"] =
---> 11 pd.cut(schoolSummary["Per Student Budget"], bins, labels = labels)

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest, duplicates)
    232                               include_lowest=include_lowest,
    233                               dtype=dtype,
--> 234                               duplicates=duplicates)
    235 
    236     return _postprocess_for_cut(fac, bins, retbins, x_is_series,

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right, labels, precision, include_lowest, dtype, duplicates)
    335 
    336     side = 'left' if right else 'right'
--> 337     ids = _ensure_int64(bins.searchsorted(x, side=side))
    338 
    339     if include_lowest:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm confused, because I did not use '<' in the code at all. I also used

```
print(type(schoolSummary["Per Student Budget"]))
```

and it is a series object, so I don't know what 'int' and 'str' it's referring to. Is it a problem with my bins or labels?

Comment: What does schoolSummary.info() return? If object, then it is a string..... Try 
 `ss = pd.to_numeric(schoolSummary)` then `pd.cut(ss, bins, labels = labels)`

Comment: Do you know that the upper bin-label does correspond with the bin? Your upper boundary is 650,where the label says 675

Comment: @Zanshin Yes, I had two other easy clarification questions I was saving to ask my instructor; thank you

Comment: @ScottBoston I think I understand now, that I need to check the type of the actual values I am using to bin? Is that correct? And the ‘<‘ is behind the scenes when .cut is checking to see if that value is more or less than the values I put in bin =[]? I will try this when I get home from work tonight

Answer (score 0):

Due to low rep, I can't comment to your question,

You must try the following

```
bins = [575, 600, 625, 650]
labels = [
    "$575-$599",
    "$600-$624",
    "$625-$649",
    "$650-$675"
]
for bin_ in bins:
    schoolSummary["Spending Range"] = pd.cut(schoolSummary["Per Student Budget"], bin_, labels = labels)
```

Because `bin` takes `int` type, instead of a `list`.